# Opera in arch can't play some videos

Tags: arch-linux, video, browser, opera

Problem:
Opera in arch Linux can't play some youtube videos.

```
pacman -Q opera
opera 78.0.4093.184-1

uname -a 
Linux arch 5.13.13-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 26 Aug 2021 19:14:36 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Opera browser not like chrome that has own codecs, opera need some codecs to work well.

**Solution**
for arch users:

```
sudo pacman -S opera-ffmpeg-codecs
```

Other distributions search on :

```
opera-ffmpeg-codecs
```

on your package manager.